# Bubble/droplet breakage/splitting vs Bubble(droplet) breakage(splitting)

Tags: grammar

Which one of the following sentences is grammatically correct to be used in a scientific article:

1. Bubble/droplet breakage/splitting

or

2. Bubble(droplet) breakage(splitting)

Comment: The person gave me their bag.

Comment: In fact I want to say one of these two: "Bubble/droplet breakage/splitting" or "bubble(droplet) breakage(splitting)"

Comment: Then say it!!!!

Comment: Putting 50% of a population in parentheses is the worst choice of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's sometimes no ideal solution to this problem, which can be very real.

The options I can think of are:

1. The traditional approach: use unisex "he". Simple, but dated and sexist.

> He gave me his bag

2. Use singular "they". This has a long tradition, but is considered bad form in some books. That said, bad grammatical form is probably a lesser evil (and less career-damaging) than being sexist.

> They gave me their bag.

If you can avoid using a pronoun for verb subjects, it's marginally more acceptable:

> A person gave me their bag.

3. Use the passive voice. This can be a good solution, especially in scientific style

> I was given a bag (by the person)
> The person's bag was given to me

4. Use he/she, as you suggest. Ugly, but non-sexist

> He/She gave me his/her bag

For possibly marginally better style, try s/he:

> S/he gave me his/her bag.

5. Use it. Singular where they isn't, but too impersonal, and a bad idea unless you want to objectify or offend the person.

> It gave me its bag.

This might be ok if the sentence is clearly impersonal and scientific, but probably singular they is still preferable:

> The subject gave me its bag.

6. Alternative gender pronouns in the text. Some authors do this. It can be confusing, and can suggest a gender where you don't know one

> She gave me her bag [...] Another person gave me his bag later, and he told me....

7. Use a neologism such as Xe, xir. None of these are yet standard, and they may in some contexts be seen as making a political statement

> Xe gave me xir bag.

8. Use nouns and other determiners. Ugly, but sometimes less ugly than sexism.

> The person gave me the bag

9. Use feminine pronouns. There's a long history of masculine pronouns being the default, which is sexist, so it might be good to balance things out:

> She gave me her bag

10. Write in a language other than English, where grammatical gender doesn't exist (Turkish?), or can be used to excuse sexism (French?)
11. Put a disclaimer in the text, like "I've used feminine pronouns for the sake of flowing prose, but these should be taken as referring to somebody of any gender / sex / anti-category".

Wikipedia has a [decent summary of the options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun).

Comment: Please re-read the question. It was not worded the way it was actually going to be used

Comment: Oh good lord, that's different. I'd vote for the brackets.